# Subject-verb agreement with "whether"

Tags: verb-agreement, agreement, disjunction, grammatical-person, whether

Which of the following choices makes this sentence is grammatically correct? or is there a better approach?

> It's unclear whether he/him or I/me is/are first in line.

Comment: You may also be interested in looking at the other questions about [subject-verb agreement in sentences with disjunction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb-agreement+disjunction?sort=votes&pageSize=30). To summarize, most textbooks/usage guides say that proximity agreement is standard (which would lead to "whether he or I am" in this case), but this actually often sounds awkward to native speakers, and as far as I know there is no deep linguistic reason why proximity agreement must be the correct way to resolve the problem.

Comment: See John Lawler's answer here for a linguist's perspective: [“My brother or one of my sisters” — singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/68236/77227)

Answer (score 0):

Only one of you can be first in line, so it has to be *is*. "which of us is first in line" would be a neat way of avoiding the problem posed by *whether he is*/*whether I am*.

Comment: So it would be "It's unclear whether he or I is first in line."?

Comment: Yes, it would be that.